# Windows 7 blocking Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: windows-7

I have 2 computers one windows 7 64bit ultimate and one windows xp pro. XP pro can connect to my team foundation server 2010 through test manager 2010 no problem.

Windows 7 can't:

> "Automatic connection to the following
>   team project failed: Test101 on server
>   http://.....:8080/tfs/
>   defaultcollection. Click Refresh to
>   display all currently available team
>   project, then connect tot he project
>   that you want to use."

I get this error every time.

So I don't know if windows 7 now blocks out going stuff too or what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to the firewall when you say:

> So I don't know if windows 7 now blocks out going stuff too or what is going on.

The Windows 7 firewall does block outgoing connections as well as incoming ones - unlike the XP one which only blocks incoming connections.

So you need to allow this connection. As I'm not using Windows 7 on this machine I can't check the steps you need to do that, so I won't guess.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered and accepted but if it helps anyone else the solution for us was to install http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2387011 from http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=31858

Then if that doesn't fix the connection issue (which it didn't for us) - open VS2010, click Team Explorer and see if you get an error about "Domain\User needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: View instance-level information", if so goto TFS Admin console > Application Tier > Administer Security > in the Global Security dialog > select [TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Valid Users > tick allow "View instance-level information"